# WinUI: does property "Disabled" exist for checkbox?

Tags: c#, winui-3

I read MSDN for WinUI but haven't found any information about how to disable checkbox. If it's exists, what's the name of property?

If it doesn't, how should I control, that checkbox cannot be changed? By overriding `onClick`?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/winui/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.control.isenabled?view=winui-3.0 ?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar shame on me... Thank you so much. Can you write an answer? I want to mark it as an solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. `Disabled` doesn't exists, but all controls have `Enabled` property, and you can set it to False. This will disable your CheckBox, as you want.

Comment: Controls have an `IsEnabled` property, `Enabled` does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably looking for the [`IsEnabled`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/windows-app-sdk/api/winrt/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.control.isenabled) property, available to all `Control`s.

Comment: 404 - Page not found; IsEnabled seems to be not available anymore?!

Comment: @DominicJonas Don't you love how not even documentation links are reliable anymore. I updated it.